# Java typecasting for retrieving integer part of a double as double

Tags: java, casting

I sometimes tend to use (double)(long)(a*b/c)   to store the integer part of the result as double. This works well for negative numbers too.

Is there any better way to achieve the same thing as I believe typecasting is a costly operation.

Please note I'm looking for Integer part of the number and not the rounded value.
For eg :

```
MyObj.setDouble((double)(long)(522.99))
MyObj.getDouble() returns 522.0 and not 523.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: You believe? Have you performed any profiling to determine that this is a significant performance hit in your real application?

Comment: Don't guess, measure, because you will be surprised how often you are wrong, even if you have been doing this sort of thing for more than a decade. ;)  Usually `Math.floor` and `Math.round` is 2-4x slower than using casts, but you should test that for yourself.

Comment: Well, I haven't performed any profiling on this. My bad. I shouldn't have jumped to the conclusion without proof. Although I want to get rid of two step typecasting as this looks ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`Math.rint(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint%28double%29) or [`Math.round(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29).  Regardless of performance differences it's at least more clear and concise.

**[Edit]**

In response to your clarified question - "how do I get the *integer part* of a double without casting" (despite your title asking about *rounding*), try this:

```
public static double integerPart(double d) {
  return (d <= 0) ? Math.ceil(d) : Math.floor(d);
}
integerPart(522.99); // => 522d
integerPart(-3.19); // => -3d
```

Of course, this form is likely no faster than casting since it's using a comparison and a method call.

Comment: This won't solve my problem as I want the Integer part and not the rounded value.

Comment: @ManishMulani: see my updated answer.  Also, consider editing your question (esp. title) to specifically ask about getting the *integer part* of a number instead of *rounding*.

Comment: I used to use this approach (ceil and floor) until after I figured that Math.ceil(-0.12) returns -0.0 and not 0.0 . Unfortunately equals() method behaves differently for -0.0 and 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is not an issue here. But code `(double)(long)(a*b/c)` is ugly. You actually do not need casting at all if you assign the result to `double variable:

`double d = a*b/c;` exactly the same as `double d = (double)(long)a*b/c;`

You actually never need to perform casting when moving from lower to upper types. It is correct for primitives (e.g. `int` -> `double`) and for classes (e.g. `ArrayList` -> `List`).

Answer (score 0):

What about `Math.floor(double)` I cant see the difference between integer part and rouding it down.

Comment: This won't work for negative numbers. Math.floor(-3.19) would give -4.0